# Cant see attachments attached to emails

Tags: email, attachment, email2case

We have email-to-case set up and some emails contain attachments. Salesforce labels what emails have attachments, but they do not give us the option to view the attachments.

[image]

How can we view these attachments?

Comment: Do you check the permissions on  Attachment ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the activity list section > click on the email (activity subject) > then in the description/notes section you'll see a link - this is your attachment.

Refer below links for more details:

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000817P
https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008nRVIAY

Hope this helps!

Thanks!